# Vectorized Computation of Compositional Variance

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, vectorization

Given an *n X m* matrix with entries *x<sub>i, j</sub>*, the [*compositional variance*](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/lib/exe/fetch.php/pessoais:abtmartins:a_concise_guide_to_compositional_data_analysis.pdf) is an *m X m* matrix, with the *i, j* entry including the expression

*∑<sub>k = 1</sub><sup>n</sup> [ ln<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>k, i</sub> / x<sub>k, j</sub>)]*

(it includes other, easily calculated, expressions).

This is very easy to calculate in a loop, but how can it be calculated using vectorization?

---

Here is the crappy loop code:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=float)

v = np.zeros((3, 3))

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(2):
            v[i, j] += np.log(x[k, i] / x[k, j])**2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant something like `(np.log(x[k, i] / x[k, j])**2)` in NumPy terms, being summed over for `k = 1:n`, one vectorized approach could be suggested with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
((np.log(x[:,:,None]/x[:,None])**2)).sum(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. The broadcasting you write is interesting, and I will look into it, but I disagree with the assumption on the intent: I meant log-squared.

Comment: :-) IDK, yet, as I don't yet understand what you did. Many thanks for the answer, though. I intend to try it, of course. Appreciated!

Comment: @AmiTavory I guess you could add the loop code that would use otherwise in the question? That could be used for verification :)

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion, Divakar - I will do it ASAP (can't right now).